# ColdFusion 10 scheduled task can't be paused

Tags: coldfusion, centos, scheduled-tasks

I am running CF10 on CentOS 6.5. When I create a scheduled task, it starts and runs fine, however, if I want to pause it, CF tells me that it paused, but the task keeps running. If I try and edit the task (how often it is recurring, for example), I get an error saying that the task already exists:

```
An error occured scheduling the task. Unable to store Job
:'SERVERSCHEDULETASK#$%^DEFAULT.job_JOBNAME' because one already
exists with this identification.
```

The interesting thing is that this is happening inconsistently. I've created a second scheduled task and that seems to be able to pause and start without a problem.

Any ideas as to why CF is not letting me pause or edit the scheduled task?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So it turns out that ColdFusion does not like colons in task names i.e. "Parent: Child". I'll chalk it up to poor input validation on Adobe's part.